# Lint fails when builing Android Studio project with gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint

I'm using gradle to build an Android Studio project:

```
$ ./gradlew build
```

when the process reach to 94%, I got following error:

```
---------------------------------------------
:lint FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lint'.
> String index out of range: -2
---------------------------------------------

I re-run the build with --stacktrace, I got the exception stack:

-------------------

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lint'.
> String index out of range: -2

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':lint'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.TypoLookup.writeDatabase(TypoLookup.java:321)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.TypoLookup.createCache(TypoLookup.java:210)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.TypoLookup.get(TypoLookup.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.TypoLookup.get(TypoLookup.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.TypoDetector.beforeCheckFile(TypoDetector.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.ResourceVisitor.visitFile(ResourceVisitor.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkResourceFolder(LintDriver.java:1869)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkResFolder(LintDriver.java:1818)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:1010)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:439)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:382)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:115)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.runLint(Lint.groovy:190)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.this$4$runLint(Lint.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$this$4$runLint$3.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lintAllVariants(Lint.groovy:79)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$lintAllVariants$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lint(Lint.groovy:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more

-------------------
```

This cannot be avoided by following:

```
lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
}
```

and this looks more like a problem about my environment.

Please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug on version 1.3.0 of the Android Gradle plugin, it's fixed now on version 1.3.1 (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181820), so just update your project's **build.gradle** to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
```